# I'm stuck with this puzzle not knowing how to go about this. It will be helpful if anyone gives me an idea how to think or solve this

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

**Ritik** - the daydreamer Ritik is a man of dreams, he keeps dreaming day and night, wondering about space and time, sci-fi and a lot more. Today is yet another day when he dreamed about a Galactic Grid where he was supposed to rescue his friend **Kriti**.

Now, this Grid is slightly unusual consisting of two species Vilgax and Arkaknight. *Vilgax is bad and can freeze you* for some time whereas *Arkaknight is good and lets you jump from one place to another.* The Grid is made up of m rows and n columns. Each cell consists of an integer either positive, negative or zero.There are exactly two zeroes one at top-left corner and the other at the bottom-right corner of the grid representing initial positions of Ritik and Kriti respectively. A positive integer represents an Arkaknight. It gives you the power to jump from cell to another containing the same integer anywhere within the grid. For example - a cell containing 2 can let you jump to any other cell containing 2 in the grid if there is one. A negative integer represents a Vilgax. It freezes for a certain period of time that is you cannot move for certain units of time represented by the absolute value of the integer present in that cell.For example, a cell containing -3 makes you freeze for 3 units of time in that cell i.e you cannot move or jump to any other cell. Ritik can also move to any cell that shares a common wall i.e adjacent to each other ( top, left, right and bottom ) within the grid. It takes one unit of time to jump from one cell to another. Your task is to tell the minimum units of time taken by Ritik to reach Kriti given the grid of m x n. The input Format First line of input contains the number of rows - M. Second line of input contains the number of columns - N. Then M lines of input follows each containing N integers respectively.

> Note: The Positive integers will range from [ 1, M * N ] both inclusive and negative integers can range from `[-1, -( M * N ) ]` both inclusive. Constraints `1 <= M <= 1000 1 <= N <= 1000` Output Format Print the minimum units of time taken by Ritik to reach Kriti.

**Sample TestCase 1**

```
Input 3 
3 
0 2 3 
-1 2 -3 
3 2 0
```

**Output** 3

Comment: This is really hard to follow. Please provide some illustrations, code you've tried, etc. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach this puzzle..That is what I'm seeking help with..please find the link below to this puzzle may be it will help you understand better...https://brainly.in/question/2827213

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to **construct a directed graph** from your input and **search the shortest path** in that graph.

Constructing the graph

- For each grid cell x construct a node N(x).
- For two grid cells x and y that share a positive number or are adjacent to each other connect the two nodes N(x) and N(y) by building two
  edges E(N(x), N(y)) and E(N(y), N(x)) with associated cost 1.
- For a grid cell x holding a negative number k  add |k| to the cost of all outgoing edges E(N(x), N(y)) of N(x).

Once you have the graph find the shortest path starting from node corresponding to the upper left grid cell and ending at the node corresponding to the lower right grid cell using [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for example

Comment: "For two grid cells x and y that share a positive number build two edges E(N(x), N(y)) and E(N(x), N(y)) with associated cost 0." I think the cost associated here would be 1 here. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Yes, this was not clear from the question, but after checking the example I figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to construct a **weighted directed graph** from your input and search the shortest path in that graph.

Constructing the **weighted directed graph**

- For each grid cell x construct a node N(x).
- For two grid cells x and y that share a **same** positive number or are
  adjacent to each other connect the two nodes N(x) and N(y) by
  building two edges E(N(x), N(y)) and E(N(y), N(x)) with associated
  weight 1.
- For a grid cell x holding a negative number k add |k| to the weight of
  all outgoing edges E(N(x), N(y)) of N(x). **i.e. |k|+1, where 1 is added for a move.**

Once you have the graph find the shortest path starting from node corresponding to the upper left grid cell and ending at the node corresponding to the lower right grid cell using **FLOYD WARSHALL ALGORITHM**

Comment: Why Floyd Warshall? You are given start and end node, so you do not need all pairs shortest paths.